# Python -Datetime function

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a coding Homework question that states:
Find the function that creates a date object and find the function that returns today’s date. Find the number of days in between today and January 1, 1970? The answer should be 17057 if today is 2016-9-13.

I am new to python and cannot figure out how to do write a function that converts each year into a number of days and totals it and then find the number of days that have passed from January 1, 1970 till now. Any Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted thus far, OP? Have you looked at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: "Find the function" ... "Find the number of days".  Your homework description says nothing about writing a function.

Comment: `import datetime;(datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)).days`

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

print((datetime.date.today() - datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)).days)

more Google and read document.